# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

how to solve this issue.... any alternative or how to increase memory??

```
12-03 15:24:21.302: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(423): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-03 15:24:21.302: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(423):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:468)
12-03 15:24:21.302: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(423):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:659)
12-03 15:24:21.302: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(423):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:720)
12-03 15:24:21.302: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(423):     at com.example.my.Map.stringtoArray(Map.java:270)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you show us some code

Comment: Alternative to...what?  You haven't explained what you're doing at all.

Comment: You can only increase max memory per app limit on rooted devices. So if you're planning to publish an app on the Market, it's better to handle the data differently in a way that they don't use that much memory. Please explain your case a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When and where this is happening?

If you use Eclipse you can increase its memory allocation by - http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-allocate-more-memory-to-eclipse.html

In other case - you can increase the memory of the emulator - when you create new emulator there is option to set its memory. The default is 16MB, you can increase it to what you want (I recommend to check the targeted phone's memory heap).

Edit: As Mathias Lin said, changing the heap allocation of rooted device is UNACCEPTABLE!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like might be working with a very large String. If you're working with a large amount of characters from a file or something, then it's better to use the Reader and Writer classes to process the data as a stream. Without seeing any code to know what you're trying to do, though, this is just a guess.